# Meteor: Check if collection is defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

There is a complex method function, which takes some data from different collections. These collection get defined in some (optional) packages. 
Now I need to check if the collection is defined - which means that the package is added to the project.

I tried to use an `if`, but this doesn't work. I still get the error `Articles is not defined` and the script aborts.

```
Meteor.methods({
    data: function () {

        if (Articles) {
            Articles.find(
                { parent: null }, 
                { fields: { title: true } } 
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this depending on how the collection is defined. Assuming it's a global variable, you should be able to safely test for it like this:

```
var root = Meteor.isClient ? window : global;
if (root.Articles) {...}
```

Also see [collections by reference](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/collections-by-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check if it's `undefined`.

```js
'use strict'; // Just to make sure we would get a reference error

if (typeof Articles === 'undefined') {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText = 'No articles here';
}
```

```html
<pre>Articles?</pre>
```